# How big does my robo hamster cage have to be?

Tags: hamsters, cage

So I bought a cage on amazon for around $70 and you can see the specs in the image[image: Bought hamster cage]

so anyway, it was pretty expensive and if its too small i dont think i want to give it up. If you think its too small, would it be okay to attach a bin cage or something, via tube?

Answer (score 4):

I am going by the numbers German pet-experts give; those are numbers for "this hamster will be really really happy", not "the hamster can manage with this", and are way above what the average store would ever give you.
Good thing about Hamsters and connected cages: they like tunnels anyway, so expansion is quiet manageable.

What worries me about the cage is the wheel! Could you check the size for this? The hamster should be able to run without bending it's back, and that means a 8inch-diameter at least.

Hamsters should ideally have at least 775 in² (0.5 m²) ground-space. So, you are below that.

BUT: as a "base", this cage is actually surprisingly well designed. My advice take would be:

- Keep the cage
- Remove the wheel
- Split up the lower half: Partly filled with sand, partly with hay and substrate for digging.
- Hamsters like tunnels and such: yes, you can have a tunnel/tube to another section of habitat. If your Hamster seems to dislike the tube, make it a DARK tube.
- Have a larger habitat-part at the other end of that tube. You can build that one yourself, or try to find a cheap used aquarium (if you are lucky, you may get one that's leaky, which is bad for fish, but okay for hamsters ;))